# Binary tree traversal abstraction

Tags: tree, traversal, abstraction, tree-traversal

I'm trying to explain to non-computer science major student with many questions.

(1)What traverses tree? Is it just logic or actual on off switch generates 1s and 0s traveling the circuit board? where is this tree and node exists CPU/Memory in between?

(2)If it is 1s and 0s HOW the circuits understand the line for example p=p.getLeft();

I said search the google or wiki.

Comment: There's no instant way to grok the electrical and semiconductor underpinnings of computation AND all the layers of abstraction between that and high-level language compilers!  But you'll probably find the best general overview in a published book that's gone through an editorial process, something like "How Computers Work" http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0789736136/

Answer (score 2):

A tree is an abstraction that we put on top of a certain collection of sequences of 0s and 1s that could be anywhere (in a CPU's registers, in a CPU's cache, in memory, etc.). The traversal of such is a sequence of CPU instructions that encapsulate the logic necessary to traverse the tree.

As for how the circuits understand the line `p = p.getLeft();`, the compiler has done the job of translating that instruction to the necessary machine instructions that the CPU understands and executes.

Honestly, it's best to think abstractly here. If you want to understand binary tree traversal think at that level of abstractions. If you want to understand how computers work at the level of 0s and 1s, forget about binary trees and study computer architecture instead.

Finally note that 0s and 1s are also just an abstraction over the true mechanism.

Comment: hmm, I would say there are plenty layers of abstractions between, don't forget about JVM, JIT, OS precaching of executables, memory management...
if that student is really interested, try to bring him assembler or even some registry instruction code.

Comment: @Gabriel Ščerbák: and don't forget that even "x86 assembly", for example, on today's Core 2 Duo and whatnots Intel and AMD cpus etc. is yet another abstracted layer. Modern CPUs are really more like RISCs that have a hackish abstracted layer so that they "work" more or less like their ancestors. So each one of our "assembly CISC instruction" is typically translated into several RISC instructions but hardly anyone knows this and think current CPUs are CISC even though they're just *programmed as if they were CISCs*, but they're not.

Comment: yeah, I heard about that, actually microprogramming makes it even more interesting...
CS is all about abstractions